# Cannot find module 'body-parser'

Tags: javascript, node.js, crud

O código Node apresenta esse erro:
[image: Alguém sabe o que pode ser?]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. [Veja mais sobre isso nesse link - Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774)

Comment: Uma dica, nunca poste fotos de códigos, coloque o código, e coloque apenas fotos de telas que seriam de uma aplicação front-end, ou mobile. Coloque imagens de relacionamento de banco de dados, mas nunca de código. Coloque o código e também o erro que aparece em tela.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 3):

Você colocou o nome da lib errado.

Não é `const bodyparser = require('body-parse')`.

Esqueceu um "r".

O certo é `const bodyparser = require('body-parser')`

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o express versão >=  4.16.0 não é mais necessário instalar o body-parser para utilizar o express.
Segue o link do pr com o merge: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2211
Que foi mergeado no dia 25/09/2017.

A maneira correta é utilizar o próprio express para habilitar as funcionalidades do body parser, segue um exemplo:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); //esta linha ativa o body-parser.

app.use(require('./server/index'));

module.exports = app;
```

Caso não queira utilizar esta abordagem, você deve instalar a lib [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Para isso basta utilizar o comando:

```
$ npm install body-parser
```

Segue um exemplo completo de como utilizar esta estratégia:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
cors({ credentials: true, origin: true });
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use('/', require('./server/index'));
//declaracao de rotas
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).json({msg: "not found"})
});

module.exports = app;
```